# Can you use sampling to normalize data?

Tags: normalization, glm, normal-distribution, normalize

***Context***

I have a retail data set that contains sales for a large number of customers. Some of these customers received a marketing treatment (i.e. saw a TV ad or similar) while others did not.  The data is very messy with most customers having $0 in sales, some having negative, some positive, a lot of outliers/influential cases etc.  Ultimately I am trying to "normalize" the data so that assumptions of the General Linear Model (GLM) are met and I can thus use various well-known statistical tools (regression, t-Test, etc.).  **Transformations have failed to normalize the data.**

***Question***

**Is it appropriate to sample groups of these customers so that the data starts to become more normal? Would doing so violate any assumptions for the GLM? Are you aware of any literature on this subject?**

***Clarification***

For example, instead of looking at 20,000 individual customers (20,000 groups of 1) I could pool customers into groups of 10 (2,000 groups of 10) and calculate their mean sale.  Theoretically, the data should begin to normalize as all of these random draws from the population begin to cluster around the population mean with some standard error.  I could keep breaking them into larger groups (i.e. 200 groups of 100) until the data is relatively normal and then proceed with my analysis.